# Does adding drawables add space? Android

Tags: android, drawable

In android project there are multiple folders, I know you can simply override these with one 'Drawable' folder.

My question is: When people download my app, will it take up more room if I have manually catered to all the different **Drawable** folders instead of just overriding them with one?

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept the answer if you have got yours.

Comment: You can't accept and answer for 10 minutes after you have posted the question

Comment: i think now you can..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, different **`Drawable`** is for different **dpi** based device screen and its part of **`APK`**.

When you download **APK** then even drawable is also part of it and it gets stored on device and it does take space.

Answer (score 1):

yea, but your app will be slightly slower, cause android has to re-size the images (whereas if you have different folders it uses the respective images)

Answer (score 0):

Different Drawable folders in android directory is for supporting different screen sizes. for better UI experience you should put drawables in appropriate folders.I think you should have look into it before proceeding further [Know android project directories](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)